# Flask web service that can access external cameras and send video streaming

Tags: python, web-services, opencv, flask, video-streaming

First that all sorry about my not so good English skills and i appreciate the corrections.

I have tried to build a python program that can access the camera through a Flask web service, this is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen():
    i = 1
    while i < 10:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + str(i) + b'\r\n')
        i += 1


def get_frame():
    camera_port = 0

    ramp_frames = 100

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)  # this makes a web cam object

    i = 1
    while True:
        retval, im = camera.read()
        imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', im)[1]
        stringData = imgencode.tostring()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + stringData + b'\r\n')
        i += 1

    del (camera)


@app.route('/calc')
def calc():
    return Response(get_frame(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)
```

And the html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('calc') }}">
    <!-- <h1>{{ url_for('calc') }}</h1> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem i have with this is when I run it in my laptop and Flask deploys.  I access the service from a different device  doesn't use the device's cam, but activates my laptop's webcam.

**Is it possible to make the service use the camera of the device from which I access it(client) instead the laptop's(server) camera?**